# Orthogonal projection of angles

Tags: trigonometry, projection

This has probably already been answered but I can't find any solution using only high-school trigonometry. I'm not a native English speaker, so I probably lack the proper wording to find what I was looking for. Anyway:

In a plan $P$, I have two secant lines $d_1$ and $d_2$ making an angle of $\alpha$.
I have a second plan $P'$ containing $d_2$ and making an angle of $\beta$ with $P$ (see image below).

[image: orthogonal projection of angles]

Using only $\alpha$, $\beta$ and the basic trigonometric functions, I would like to express the angle $\alpha '$ made by the projection of $d_1$ and $d_2$ onto the $P'$ plan.

I came myself to the conclusion that $\alpha ' = atan(tan \beta . cos \alpha)$, but I'm not confident at all in the path I followed to reach that. **It appears I was wrong. See answer below.**

Comment: Is $d_2$ always along the “hinge,” then?

Comment: Yes, $d_2$ is always on the intersection of the planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Filling in a bit more of your diagram, we are projecting the angle $\alpha$
orthogonally onto the angle $alpha'$.
Since it is an orthogonal projection, the image of $C$ is a point $D$
that is the foot of the perpendicular from $C$ to the plane of $\alpha'.$

Moreover, $CD$ lies in a plane perpendicular to both of the first two planes.
So have right triangles $\triangle ABC,$ $\triangle ABD,$ and $\triangle BDC$
with right angles $\angle ABC,$ $\angle ABD,$ and $\angle BDC$ respectively.

Taking the length of $AB$ as $1$ for simplicity,
we have $$BC = \tan\alpha$$ (due to $\triangle ABC$) and therefore
$$BD = \tan\alpha \cos\beta$$ (due to $\triangle BDC$).
Looking at $\triangle ABD,$ we find that 
$$\tan\alpha' = \tan\alpha \cos\beta.$$

Comment: Thank you very much David. It helped me a lot in understanding how to solve such problems. One question though: you said "$BE = \tan\alpha \cos\beta$". Isn't that $BD$ instead?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Well spotted!