# How to calculate orthogonal distances from point coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry, projection, coordinates

I am not 100% sure I have worded my question correctly, but i hope explanation will be helpful.

The problem itself is taken form real life situation, where 2 points have been measured and their coordinates are known. I can calculate sloping distance as well as planar distance between known points, but thats about it.
I need to solve for X and Y

I have seen a similar problem solved in this forum, but the givens there were different and unfortunately im not strong in trigonometry.

[Problem schematic, orthogonal projection of triangles constructed from 2 known points and an angle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiYAq.png)

EDIT: Was asked for a new picture. Perhaps this one is better.
[Need to solve for x and y, need their distance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgndJ.png)

EDIT: Further explaining the problem, I am sorry i didnt think of adding this too at first[Misaligned axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MtWW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes i noticed. I hoped the picture would appear under the text too as it is here, but its my first question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279677/orthogonal-projection-of-angles I need to solve for X and Y

Comment: Your picture is making it difficult to see the situation clearly. If you draw the right picture I don't think there is any calculation in seeing X and Y.

Comment: Here, i did a new picture, I hope this helps
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgndJ.png

Comment: I thought about the part where you say that theres no calculation. Perhaps i have misled you. The device i measured the coordinates with is not perpendicular to any of the axis on the pictures apart from height axis. This is an object that has been measured IRL and stationing measuring device parallel or perpendicular to planar axes makes measuring interest points difficult because i will have obstacles in my line of sight. Therefore i cannot just take the coordinate values for distances I search.

Comment: The problem as given with the new picture just allows you to read off the values of X and Y, so you are going to have to explain in more detail what the problem with that is

Comment: First thankyou for the patience. Second, sorry i have not provided full info, thhinking a scheme would be enough. 
In the 3rd picture you see 2 axis that are not parallel. This in turn makes distances from coordinates inaccurate. Easiest way to fix that would be to make sure axis are parralel, then indeed I just need to take the coordinate values, but that introduces measurement problems, so i was looking for a way to still get correct distances even when my axis are random.